# how to commit changes in detached HEAD to a new branch in git

Tags: git, branch, git-detached-head

I had a tag, at a very old revision of a repository.
I have checked it out

```
   git checkout mytag
```

Now I am in detached HEAD state.

I have made some meaningful modifications. I would like to create a new branch `mybranch_deviated` locally and remotely, and commit all the meaningful changes to it. How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With all of your code modifications you can simply create a new branch

```
git checkout -b mybranch_deviated
```

Then commit your changes

```
git add .
git commit -m 'some meaningful modifications'
```

And push the newly created branch to the server

```
git push -u origin branch_derivated
```

Answer (score 2):

Just checkout a new branch from the current point:

```
git checkout -b mybranch_deviated
```

This should work whether or not you have already made some commits from the detached HEAD state.  If you have, then those commits should be part of the new branch.